# does tcolorbox box support "middle collor"?

Tags: tcolorbox

please consider the following mwe:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}
\tcbset{oversize,
        enhanced,
        colframe=red!75!black,
        interior style={top color=blue!30,
                        middle color=yellow, % <--- hasn't any influence
                        bottom color=red!30}
        }
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[11]
\begin{tcolorbox}
\lipsum[12]
\end{tcolorbox}
\end{document}
```

it compile without warnings and errors, however middle color doesn't appear:

[image]

do i miss something or this is not supported?

**addendum:**

sometimes (usual) is very helpful to read instructions (in this case packages manual) :-). with help of [daleif](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/3929/daleif) comments and latter with his answer the source of the problem was indicated and then solved. i'm a little embarrassed now :-) (or better :-( )

proof of solution. with use :

```
\tcbset{oversize,
        enhanced,
        colframe=red!75!black,
        interior style={top color=blue!30,
                        bottom color=red!30,
                        middle color=yellow % <--- now has influence
                        }
        }
```

the result is as i expected on the first place:

[image]

Comment: I cannot get `middle color` to work in a sample purely tikz doc ....

Comment: Oh, it is position dependent, seems `bottom color` sets `middle color` from it self and `top color`, add it manually again after `bottom color` should work

Comment: @daleif, thank you very much for comment! it actually solve my problem because i went to read `tikz` again :-). there is stated: *Note: Since both top color and bottom color change the middle color, this option should be
given last if all of these options need to be given*. considering this, all works!

Comment: Lol, I was even staring at that page, never saw the **note...**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The manual explicitly states:

> Note: Since both `top color` and `bottom color` change the `middle color`,
>   this option (`middle color`) should be given last if all of these options need to be given

(I never noticed that one either...)